# How to use data from csv files with pygame?

Tags: python, csv, pygame

I'm making a 2d platformer using pygame and at the moment am trying to put in a camera system. This is the code I am using for it, cut from the game:

```
class Camera():
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

    def camera_move(camera, target_rect):
        x = -target_rect.center[0] + HALF_WIDTH
        y = -target_rect.center[1] + HALF_HEIGHT
        camera.topleft += (pygame.Vector2((x, y)) - pygame.Vector2(camera.topleft)) * 0.06
        camera.x = max(-(camera.width-SCREEN_WIDTH), min(0, camera.x))
        camera.y = max(-(camera.height-SCREEN_HEIGHT), min(0, camera.y))

        return camera


player_x = 340
player_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 190
player = Player(player_x, player_y)
entities = pygame.sprite.Group()


#load in level
f = open("Levels/level1.csv", "r")
data = csv.reader(f)
data = [row for row in data]
f.close()
world = World(data)


total_level_width = len(data[0])*TILE_SIZE[0]
total_level_height = len(data)*TILE_SIZE[1]
camera = Camera(Camera.camera_move, total_level_width, total_level_height)
entities.add(player)
```

However, when I run this it comes up with an error:

```
total_level_width = len(data[0])*TILE_SIZE[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried replacing `data` with `list(data)` but it comes up with the same error.

Comment: What is `TILE_SIZE`?

Comment: It seems like `TILE_SIZE` is an `int` not a `list`

Comment: Your example code does not show us what `TILE_SIZE` is.  As mentioned previously it is probably and int. Split that line into two lines: `total_level_width = len(data[0])` then `total_level_width = total_level_width*TILE_SIZE[0]`. Now where is the error? Please read [mre].

Answer (score 0):

data is already a list at this point, so calling list(data) will not change the data type.

The problem is TILE_SIZE[0]. TILE_SIZE is an integer, which is not subscriptable. Simply removing [0] after TILE_SIZE should solve the error, but may cause other problems depending on the intended behaviour of the program.